# Key/Value pyqt QComboBox

Tags: pyqt, qcombobox

I want to use a QComboBox with the "keys" and "values" from a tuple similar to the ones used in a django models. For example I have the following structure for a person's sex.

```
SEX_CHOICES = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'))
```

The first item of the tuple contains the code of the sex that is stored in the database, and the second one the text that I want to display in the QComboBox as an item.

Is there a way in wich I could set the QComboBox value as M and it displays Male. An also when the user select the element Male I could get the selected value as M.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
cb.addItem  ( text, userData )
```

and pass the DB key as `userData`. If you need to change the current selection, use `cb.itemData()` to get the DB key of each item and compare it to the one you need.

Alternatively, record the indexes as you add items in a Python map and use this to directly look up the correct index.

To make things more easy to use, wrap the `QComboBox` with a Python class that offers setters and getters for the current DB key and which hides the mapping.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will be easy to implement. The only problem that I will have is using the custom QComboBox in Qt Designer. Is there an easy way to add the new control?

Do you think that it will be easier to use a qt model?, I have already check it and it can hold the mapping that you mention. But still having problems setting the value from the db value.

Comment: See the docs for how to build widgets in PyQt that can be used in the designer: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt4ref.html#using-python-widgets-in-qt-designer