# PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object instead of a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I followed this example [Key/Value pyqt QComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675296/key-value-pyqt-qcombobox), to store ID value to a combo-box item using the code below.

```
self.combox_widget.addItem('Apples', 'Green')
indx = self.combox_widget.currentIndex()
print self.combox_widget.itemData(indx)
```

however, I get `<PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0x02AC1A70>` on trying to retrieve the DATA value ('Green' in the example above). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most Qt APIs that set and retrieve arbitrary "data" will store it as a QVariant.

For **Python2**, by default, PyQt will automatically convert a python object *to* a QVariant when you set it, but it won't automatically convert them back again when you *retrieve* it. So you have to take an extra step to do that like this:

```
    print self.combox_widget.itemData(indx).toPyObject()
```

For **Python3**, by default, the conversion is always done automatically in both directions, so the extra step is not needed.

To workaround this difference, PyQt provides a [way to explicitly set the default mode](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) by using the `sip` module:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

This needs to be done once at the beginning of your program, *before* the other PyQt modules are imported, and will ensure that a QVariant is never returned by any Qt API.

Comment: Note: For PyQt4 4.12.2 and newer, you need to use the "PyQt4.sip" module for the setapi() call instead of the "sip" module.